# Dynamically set domain variable in sessions file of Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got this entry in my session.php:

```
'domain' => ".mytestdomain.com",
```

and I am wondering how to change it to a dynamic value like

```
'domain' => ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']",
```

preserving the starting dot, or get it from the database.php file, under which I store it as a variable:

```
  'domain' => 'mytestdomain.com',
```

adding an extra dot aswell there.

Comment: Did you tried `'domain' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],` without quote ?

Comment: I still need the starting dot.

Comment: So like this if you need the dot `'domain' => '.'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],`

Comment: Thats a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else got the same problem, I solved this by:

```
'domain' => '.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'',
```